# A square inside a triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

PQRS is a square inside an isosceles right angled triangle ABC, such that points P,Q and S lie on the sides AB, BC and AC, respectively. If BQ=8cm, PB= 4cm and PR not parallel to BC, what is the area of the triangle outside the square?

I applied sine rule in triangle APS to find length of PA which I found to be 12 and therefore AB=16 hence area =128. But this was not the correct answer.

Am I wrong?

Comment: This is not clear.  Is the inner figure a square?  You are given $PB=8$ so how could you calculate that is $12$?

Comment: sorry I have edited the question

Comment: You edited it to say $PB=4$ but that is still not compatible with it being $12$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the diagram is not an accurate figure it is just a representation of the question

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking...you change the question so often it is hard to keep up.  But, the (current) question asks for the "area outside the square" and you appear to be computing the entire area.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have not drawn this figure, this was there in my assessment sheet I have just copied and pasted it.

Comment: @KshitijSingh If AP=12 and PB=8, then AB=20 and the area of the triangle is 200, whilst the area of the square is $(4\sqrt5)^2=80$, giving an area outside of 120. What is the correct answer?

Comment: Did you mean for PB=8cm, BQ= 4cm as suggested by your diagram?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to calculate the area of $\bigtriangleup ABC$, and didn’t actually require $PQRS$ to be completely inside of it, your answer is actually right, as a quick, computer-generated diagram reveals.

[image]

However, the diagram made from the data you give is very different from the one you link. This leads me to believe that you erroneously transcribed the problem.

Comment: OP's answer is _not_ right, because the problem asks for the area of the triangle _outside_ the square. Given that the square does not fit in the triangle as claimed in the problem statement, however, I think it is impossible to say what the "correct" answer is.

Comment: @DavidK I mean, you could argue $\bigtriangleup ABC$ is the triangle outside the square, and that its area is $128$. This question really needs some clarifying.

Comment: I don't see any reasonable interpretation of "outside" such that the triangle is outside the square in the figure above.

Comment: @DavidK I answered the most reasonable interpretation I could find. If the answer isn’t edited, there’s not much I can do to improve it.

Comment: There's no reasonable interpretation. The problem is fatally flawed. And if the original intention was "what is the area of triangle $ABC$", then it was really poor form on the author's part to ask that question in such a strange way.

Comment: Your figure is extremely valuable, however, because it shows exactly why the problem is impossible.